# Xamarin.Android Error inflating PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, sharedpreferences, preferencescreen

I have a problem using PreferenceScreen, I got

> Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error
>   inflating class android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen

My goal is to build a settings page and I figured out to use to v7 version for old phones, so I would like to put a PreferenceFragmentCompat inside an Activity but I always get this error.

From NuGet I added the reference to Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Preference and Xamarin.Android.Support.v14.Preference

Below is the code I used.

Activity xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/pref_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity code:

```
public class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Settings);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
        transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.pref_container, new SettingsFragment()).Commit();
    }
}
```

PreferenceScreen xml (SettingsFragment.xml):

```
<android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Category 1">
        <android.support.v7.preference.SwitchPreferenceCompat
            android:key="key1"
            android:title="Switch Preference"
            android:summary="Switch Summary"
            android:defaultValue="true" />
        <android.support.v7.preference.EditTextPreference
            android:key="key2"
            android:title="EditText Preference"
            android:summary="EditText Summary"
            android:dialogMessage="Dialog Message"
            android:defaultValue="Default value" />    
        <android.support.v7.preference.CheckBoxPreference
            android:key="key3"
            android:title="CheckBox Preference"
            android:summary="CheckBox Summary"
            android:defaultValue="true"/>
    </android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceCategory>
</android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

PreferenceScreen fragment code:

```
public class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat
{
    public override void OnCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, string rootKey)
    {
        AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Xml.SettingsFragment);
    }
}
```

Styles:

```
  <style name="MyThemeLight.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Material</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: This error indicates that `android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceScreen` cannot be found, since you've installed the package already, can you please try to clean and rebuild your project, I tested you code by [my side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEGxp.png), it works fine.